# Add object to collection failed for ColumnCollection of table [name]

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following code:

```
IEnumerable<Table> tables = dbtables.ToList()
                                    .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("PartStats"));

 foreach (var tbl in tables)
 {
    Table JoinTable = new Table(db, "ProductMaterial");
    JoinTable.Columns.Add(tbl.Columns[0]);

    string tblName = tbl.Columns[0].Name;
    string script =
                @"ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductMaterial]  
                   WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_" + tbl.Name +
                "] PRIMARY KEY([" + s;
    string script2 = @"]) REFERENCES [dbo].[" + tbl.Name + "] ([" + tblName + "])" ;
    string newscr = string.Concat(script, script2);
    AddPrimaryKey(tbl, newscr);
```

This used to work, but now when I run it, I get this error:

> "Add object to collection failed for ColumnCollection of table ProductMaterial".

`AddPrimaryKey()` just executes the script on the SQL Server, and is fine. The problem is in the preceding code to that method call.

The server is on, I am using local admin account for the SQL Server (my windows account is an admin for the SQL Server).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps wrap the call in a check whether the column already exists on the table.

```
if (!JoinTable.Columns.Contains(tbl.Columns[0].Name)
{
    JoinTable.Columns.Add(tbl.Columns[0]);
}
```

<strike>Could it be that you're trying to add multiple `Table`s named "ProductMaterial"?</strike>

Comment: Nope. I am only adding one column from each table I am looping through. Besides, tbl itself is not ProductMaterial.

Comment: @dotnetdev: which line does the error occur on when debugging?

Comment: This line:    JoinTable.Columns.Add(tbl.Columns[0]);